# How to document the high-level structure of a Java program?

Tags: java, documentation

**Background:**
My collaborators and I are writing an article for an academic journal.
In the course of our research,
we wrote a simulation program in Java.
We want to make the simulation program freely available for others to use.
We have decided on hosting the code on a GitHub repository.
In order to make it easy for others to use,
we want to write good documentation for our program, including:

- Javadocs for each class and method
- How to use the code
- Describing the high-level structure of the code

My high-level question is:
**Could you provide a good example of the words and diagrams
    that can be used to describe the high-level structure of a program?**
This includes as sub-questions:

1. How do we show what classes are contained in which packages?
2. How do we show what packages depend on other packages?
3. How do we show how the objects/classes in the program work together?
4. We have tried to use [domain-driven design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) principles
   in the design of my code.
   How do we show the correspondence between the objects in the domain
   and the particular source code files encoding these objects?
   (See my "ubiquitous language" description of the project below.)

## What I have done so far

### Ubiquitous language

We put a "ubiquitous language" description of the code
in a file `ubiquitous-language.md`,
contents below.

The purpose of this project is to study how well a replenishment policy
performs in a simple supply chain with a single facility,
under different lead time models, report delays and demand models.

In each period, the following events occur:

1. If a **shipment** is scheduled to arrive at the **facility** at the
   current period, then the inventory level of the facility is
   incremented by X units.
2. If the **schedule** indicates that the current period is a reporting
   period, then the **facility** submits a **report** to the
   **supplier**.  The **supplier** may receive the **report**
   instantaneously, or with a delay of several weeks, as specified by
   the **schedule**.
3. If the **supplier** has received a **report**, then based on the
   **replenishment policy**, it will calculate a replenishment
   quantity of X units.  A **shipment** of X units of the product will
   be scheduled to arrive after a lead time of l periods.
4. Customers arrive at the **facility** and demand X units of the
   product.  Any unmet demand is lost.

### Source Code Structure

We put an incomplete "high-level" description of the code
in a file `structure.md`,
contents below.

#### Package Level Structure

At the highest level, the source code is organized into three packages

- `com.gly.sfs`
  The main class with the `main` method resides in this package.
- `com.gly.sfs.model`
  The domain model classes reside in this package.
- `com.gly.sfs.util`
  Helper classes reside in this package.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490

Comment: when you say "high-level structure of the code," do you just mean which classes are in which packages?  You can do that by drawing a dotted line around the classes in your class diagram that belong to a specific package, and labeling the dotted line with the package name.  It's easy enough to find [examples of class diagrams](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=979&q=uml+class+diagram+java).

Comment: Big props for releasing academic code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey See my edits to the question. Showing which classes are in which packages is more straightforward, showing how the classes work together is more tricky.

Comment: You might want to add package-level javadoc as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Normally*, you'd use UML for the purpose you describe.  UML basically breaks down into two types of diagrams:  structural and behavioral.

*Structural* diagrams include:  composition, deployment, package, class, object, and component.  *Behavioral* diagrams include:  sequence, state machine, communication, use case, activity, and interaction overview.

Depending on what you're trying to convey, you pick a few of these diagrams which best represent whatever you're trying to convey, and by so doing you allow the conversation to "move up a level".  Instead of talking about methods, parameters, and code, you're talking about sequence of interactions, or static class dependencies, or whatever diagrams you choose to create.

I've attached an example of a sequence diagram (one of the behavior diagrams).  I personally like the sequence diagram because it's right in the middle of the design artifact process -- roughly an equal number of diagrams depend on it as it expects as input.  I find that the input diagrams are typically "understood" anyway, or the sequence diagram already implies their existence.  However, sometimes I do both static class diagrams and sequence diagrams (one structural and one behavioral diagram).

http://omarfrancisco.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/sequencediagram.png

I have never seen this diagram before in my life, but I can tell a number of things about this system.  There are four major components (the nouns in your system -- typically the classes):  View, Controller, Data Proxy, and Data Provider.  The arrows are "behaviors" or method invocations.  A sequence diagram is basically good for showing a single important interaction between a bunch of components.  You have one sequence diagram for each important flow through your system.  I can tell from this particular diagram that "Controller" exposes a method called "phoneIsComplete()", which in turn depends on DataProviderProxy's "lookupPhone()" method, which in turn depends on DataProvider's "lookupPhone()" method.

Now, you might groan and think "uggg... this doesn't give me a big picture of the system -- it's just individual interactions through the system".  Depending on the sophistication of the system, that might be a valid concern (simple systems can definitely get by with just a collection of sequence diagrams).  So, we move over to the structural diagrams and we look at something like a static class diagram:

http://www.f5systems.in/apnashoppe/education//img/chapters/uml_class_diagram.jpg

Class diagrams help us figure out two important things:  cardinality, and class relationship types.  Classes can be related to one another in different ways:  association, aggregation, and composition.  Technically speaking, there's a difference between "static class relationships" and "instance relationships".  However, in practice you see these lines blurred.  The main difference is that static class relationships don't usually include cardinality.  Let's look at the example above and see what we can see.  First, we can see that "Special Order" and "Normal Order" are subtypes of "Orders" (inheritance).  We can also see that one Customer has N Orders (which may be "Normal Orders", "Orders", or "Special Orders") -- the Customer object doesn't really know.  We can also see a number of methods (in the bottom half of each class box) and properties (top half of each class box).

I could keep talking about UML diagrams for a long time, but this is the basics.  Hopefully that helps.

**TLDR;  Pick one behavioral and one structural UML diagram, learn how to create it, and you'll accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.**

Answer (score 18):

If you're having difficulty describing things like how the high-level structure of your program works, and how the classes work well together, consider the following maxim:

```
A picture is worth a thousand words.
```

The way you paint a picture about code is to *provide code examples.*  Lots of them.  This is how you create a new customer (code).  This is how you process an order (code).  Not only does this give the consumer of your code a place to start, it illustrates how all of the objects connect together and interact.  If I were using your code, the biggest favor you could do me is to provide lots of code samples.

The way you paint a picture for an end-user is to *provide screenshots.*  Lots of them.  Screenshot after screenshot that illustrates, if you want to do this task, this is what you do first, this is what you do next, etc.

Comment: +1, Code examples of common tasks is the first thing anyone trying to learn an API is going to want. Javadocs and some description of the relationship between classes will fill in the blanks, but are not sufficient.

Comment: +1 for **not** mentioning UML.

Comment: @DocBrown UML is certainly not the tool for every job. *However*, if you're modeling something that fits the pattern of one of the UML diagrams (for example, modeling class relationships), then UML *does* offer a format which readers are likely to be familiar with, and familiarity eases readability.

Comment: @DocBrown Why would UML be a bad solution in this case?

Comment: @Onno: this was a little bit ironic of mine, but I think UML has only limited support for such a "high level" description, and a very unclear semantics. But I guess using package diagrams will be ok here (as long as the UML tool will allow to draw classes within packages).

Comment: @DocBrown ok :) There are a lot of people that use UML just for drawing, but in my view you can achieve a good situational overview of your design if you have a proper understanding of the whole UML toolkit. Sometimes I get the idea that people see using UML to make a proper design as wasted time, looking at is as just a drawing toolkit. I have many experiences to the contrary, but you are correct that UML could have a better way of expressing itself in some of the diagram types. OTOH, many people think they know UML if they can globally read a class diagram, which is not true if you ask me.

Comment: @Onno: IMHO one of the most important high level diagrams are *data flow* diagrams - and after almost 20 years of UML, those kind of diagram type is still missing (and no, activity diagrams are no replacement for that). Instead, UML contains a whole lot of waste no one really needs or understands because the semantics is not clearly defined. That's why I don't like it when someone answers such a question with "use UML" as a knee-jerk reflex. Don't get me wrong: some parts of the UML are fine, and one can surely use them, even for high level docs.

Answer (score 3):

UML, while often used to model software before it is created, could be useful. There are several different diagrams that illustrate use-cases, class-interactions, etc. etc. You can see more about it [here](http://www.uml.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I find https://www.websequencediagrams.com/ an extremely useful tool for describing the interaction between components within an application, or between services in a distributed application. It just makes the process of creating and maintaining UML sequence diagrams much easier.

The nice thing is, if you consider each lifeline to be the interface or class in your application (I usually just model the big players), then each line flowing into that class represents a method that you must support.

Additionally, there are some download options to get the image. There are also some easy ways to embed the diagram in a wiki. So it's a great communication tool to describe the interaction between components or services in a system, as well as communicating that with the team.